# The number of times a function hits a particular value.

Tags: geometry

Now that I have received a good answer for the first question (about the length of a plot), I have another question that was irritating when studying cliff formations. I found it quite helpful to know how many times a plot of a function is equal to some value, which was feasible to calculate for functions with finite ranges with a known plot (not a problem in my case, as the cliff formations have a finite width, and I could also see the cliff). The problem is that this function is not continues. Thus I tried complex numbers and it kinda works. So my real question is this: given a function f with a limited range (in this case the complex numbers less than or equal to say r) and a value v, what is the length of the plot of the complex numbers z inside r where f(z)=v.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The answer you accepted to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282043/how-do-you-find-the-length-of-a-plot suggests that you may be asking about the length of a level curve of a function. If you [edit] this question to provide an actual example, with a picture, we may be able to help. The phrase "cliff formation" isn't standard mathematics, so we don't know what you mean by it.

Comment: I mean a literal cliff formation. I was away for a week as you probably didn’t notice, and made some notes after seeing some ridges on some cliffs.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Do you want $f$ arbitrary? Continuous? Holomorphic? It is easy to see that in the first two cases the set $\{f(z)=v\}$ has arbitrary cardinality.